# Regular expression for custom types

Tags: c++, objective-c, regex, grammar, regular-language

I'm interested to create a new grammar and build REGEX for the grammar.
Grammar is set of laws that allowing word or not.

For exemple i have create 5 types : A, B, C, D, E.

My grammar is all word that like ABC , ABE , ABDC, ABDE .
(A and B must, D optional and need choose C or E).

How can i create REGEX to check if the word is correct for the custom grammar?

(preference for c/c++ or objective C code)

Thanks a lot.

A = ice cream, B = cone, D = whipped cream, C = chocolate and E = vanilla.

So ice cream and cone are a must, whipper cream optional and need to know chocolate or vanilla to accept the expression

Comment: https://regex101.com/ this may help you

Comment: Can they appear in any order?

Comment: I will appreciate responses with both, means with order and without order.

Comment: Convert the words into letters `A, B, C, D & E`, sort them using `std::sort()`, then use *regex* something like `ABC?(?:D|E)` (note you have to change the letters to make essentials first, optionals second and choice third, alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(AB(C|E)D?)|(ABD?(C|E))
```

For objective C:

```
NSString *searchedString = @"ice creamconewhipped creamchocolate";//NOTE: here i dont put space
NSString *A = @"ice cream";
NSString *B = @"cone";
NSString *D = @"whipped cream";
NSString *C = @"chocolate";
NSString *E = @"vanila";
NSString *stringRegExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@%@(%@|%@)%@?)|(%@%@%@?(%@|%@))",A,B,C,E,D,A,B,D,C,E];//(AB(C|E)D?)|(ABD?(C|E))
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stringRegExp];
if ([myTest evaluateWithObject: searchedString])
{
    NSLog(@"MATCHING");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NOT_MATCHING");
}
```

Equivalent Case for Class:

```
HomeViewController *objA = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
 NSString *className1 = NSStringFromClass([objA class]);

TableViewController *objB = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
NSString *className2 = NSStringFromClass([objB class]);

CustomTextView *objD  = [[CustomTextView alloc]init];
NSString *className4 = NSStringFromClass([objD class]);

CustomTableViewCell *objC = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]init];
NSString *className3 = NSStringFromClass([objC class]);


NSString *objE;

NSString *searchedStringABDC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",className1,className2,className3,className4];//CASE ABDC/ ABCD

NSString *A = NSStringFromClass([HomeViewController class]);
NSString *B = NSStringFromClass([TableViewController class]);
NSString *D = NSStringFromClass([CustomTextView class]);
NSString *C = NSStringFromClass([CustomTableViewCell class]);
NSString *E = NSStringFromClass([AssementAndPlanView class]);

NSString *stringRegExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@%@(%@|%@)%@?)|(%@%@%@?(%@|%@))",A,B,C,E,D,A,B,D,C,E];//(AB(C|E)D?)|(ABD?(C|E))
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stringRegExp];
if ([myTest evaluateWithObject: searchedStringABDC])
{
    NSLog(@"MATCHING");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NOT_MATCHING");
}
```

or if you doesn't need the correct order, without using regex , u can check with `isKindOfClass` .  For Example:

```
if ([objA isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]&&[objB isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]]&&[objC isKindOfClass:[CustomTableViewCell class]]&&!objD&&!objE)
{
    //case ABC
    NSLog(@"case ABC");
}
else if ([objA isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]&&[objB isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]]&&[objE isKindOfClass:[AssementAndPlanView class]]&&!objC&&!objD)
{
    //case ABE
    NSLog(@"case ABE");        
}
```

Comment: So you propose that i insert the string of the class to perform regex?

Comment: @Rebecca you mean A may be an object of a class, and B may be an object of another class and so on??

Comment: Thanks @Shebin it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regular:

```
ABD?[CE]
```

Comment: I thing it will check the word with chars, not type.
A, B, D, C, E are class like ice cream, cone, whipped cream, chocolate and vanilla.
So  ice cream and cone are a must, whipper cream optional and need to know chocolate or vanilla to accept the expression

Comment: @Rebecca what you mean by type?

Comment: Mean, A, B, C, D, E are class/type and not chars (string) so If i write the (AB(C|E)D?)|(ABD?(C|E)) or ABD?[CE] in simple regex and check it with my word (array) that have number of instance like [A, B, D, E] not a string how can i check  the regex with my array?

Comment: @Rebecca Did you mean check regex with array of objects or array of string?